# Run "reload from disk" once CSS file has changed externally in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I'm running WebStorm and have two panels open - one for CSS, one for SASS. What I want is, once I modify the SASS file, the CSS file should update immediately. However, it takes about 10 seconds for this to happen. This is just a visual update however - if I refresh my browser I can see that the page has changed to reflect the modified CSS. The issue is that the CSS file does not seem to update itself quick enough, unless I close and reopen, or wait about 10 seconds.

I've tried to create a custom file watcher that watches for changes in the CSS file, and run a AutoHotKey script, which sends the keystrokes CTRL+ALT+Y. This is the keyboard shortcut to 'reload from disk'. This doesn't work either.

Is there any way to actually get the CSS file to update immediately on external changes? I have the "Synchronize External Changes" checked as well.

Comment: I'm sure you have some established workflow already (compiling Sass outside of IDE), but why not compile Sass into CSS using File Watcher in the first place? If configured correctly IDE will know what files to refresh after File Watcher program finished running.

Comment: Seems to be your post: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010874920-CSS-file-not-updating-on-external-changes-SASS- and you seem to have the File Watcher already... but it does not do as you want?..

Comment: On a second thought: the screenshot of the File Watcher is not yours ... Can you show what you have there in yours?